# Visual Studio 2008 vc++ Mysql Connect

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2008

can someone give me proper steps on how to connect to Mysql to Visual Studio 2008 c++ ?. Good web link would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Link1](http://lstigile.wordpress.com/2009/05/19/using-libmysqld-with-microsoft-visual-c-2008-express/), [Link2](http://www.functionx.com/mysqlnet/vcnet/Lesson04.htm) and [Link3](http://www.caspercomsci.com/pages/visualcplussource.htm#12).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but I was expecting a detailed explanation how to add .lib and .dll files. because it's really confusing and hard to find a proper material. I feel that mysql and vc++ is not used much. Am I correct?..

Comment: VC++ is commonly employed in all-Microsoft shops, so yes I think so too that MySQL with VC++ is somewhat atypical. I updated my answer to include some more links that are closer to what you may be looking for. Good luck!